# How to create an sql script file in TFS 2008 at designated directory automatically for developers to add sql script?

Tags: file-io, tfsbuild, msbuild-task, createfile

I have just revised my question. Actually i wan to create an empty txt/.sql file in TFS 2008 Source Control server at designated directory/folder where developers can add sql script for their part of development.

I need this file to be created automatically each time our nightly build script runs. I have created directories or folders using MakeDir task as shown below:

```
 <MakeDir Directories="$(DropLocation)\Output\x86\" />
```

**I was wondering if some task were available that could help me create an empty file in TFS. I dont want to use the EXEC command but rather a standard task.**

If there is something available in MSBuild Extension Pack or SDC for this purpose then please do share so.

Regards

> Hi all,
>
> I want to create and plan text file in
>   source control at a designated path on
>   a nightly basis when my script runs to
>   create a nighly build. How can i
>   create new plain text files anywhere
>   in the source controil using
>   TFSBuild.proj scrip/ msbuild script.
>
> Help is much appreciated.
>
> Thanks all.
>
> **Edit:**
>
> Actually i needed a way via
>   MSBuild/Team Build Tasks. Like we can
>   create using  , similarly i am looking for a task
>   that can be invoked via some standard
>   task from msbuild or team build script
>   (tfsbuild.pro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you call the `tf.exe` command line tool?

```
tf add file
```

will added `file` to source control (in the TFS folder corresponding to the current Windows folder, relative paths work), and then

```
tf checkin /noprompt
```

to checkin (the `/noprompt` in needed to avoid getting the checkin dialogue).

See `tf help` and `tf help command` for more help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But actually i needed a way via MSBuild/Team Build Tasks. Like we can create using  <MakeDir Directories="$(DropLocation)\Output\x86\" />, similarly i am looking for a task that can be invoked via some standard task from msbuild or team build script (tfsbuild.pro).

Comment: @Steve: MSBuild has an execute command task available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx